# Number of sequences $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8)$ with expressions from the set $Y = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ that satisfy $2$ conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Find the number of sequences $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8)$ with expressions from the set $Y = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ that satisfy (simultaneously) two conditions:

1. each number from the set $Y$ occurs in the sequence $(x_1, . . . , x_8)$ at least once,
2. for each $i \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \}$, the number $x_i - i$ is even.

Give a specific numerical value.

---

First condition: we will exclude the sequences that break the condition, but for now let's focus on the second one.

Second condition: the possibilities are:

- even - even = even,
- even - odd = odd,
- odd - odd = even,
- odd - even = odd.

Therefore, we need even numbers on even places and odd numbers in odd places.

Now back to the first condition: we need to put: $Y' = \{1, 3 \}$ in $(x_1, x_3, x_5, x_7)$ and $Y'' = \{2, 4 \}$ in $(x_2, x_4, x_6, x_8)$ in such way that all elements of $Y'$ and $Y''$ are used at least once. We can divide that problem into $2$ symmetric ones ($2$ digits in $4$ places, both digits used at least once).

Therefore: |sequences that we are interested in| = |all possible sequences| - |sequences with only one digit (let's say $1$ or $3$)| = $2^4 - 2$.

Then adding the second similar problem: $(2^4 - 2)^2$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your method and the answer $(2^{4}-2)^{2}$ are correct.